# Entity Framework Code First Primary Key Constraint Names

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, primary-key, code-first

Is there a way for me to control the name of the PK Index EF creates on my code first defined table?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this yet?

Comment: We moved away from EF, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903791/entity-framework-6-1-1-naming-convention-for-indexes looks like it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can name it anything you like and put `[Key]` attribute on it.

So if you have a model `Person` as below, you won't need anything like `[Key]`, iicallyt will treat `PersonId` as PK automatically with the convention `{classname}Id`

```
public class Person
{
   public int PersonId { get;set; }

   public int FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to have some different PK, then you can specify it with [Key] as below:

```
 public class Person
 {
   [Key]
   public int YourPK{ get;set; }

   public int FirstName { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was imprecise.  I am looking for the primary key _index_ name -- eg "PK_Person_YourPK" -- rather than the primary key column