# Entity Framework 6.1.1 Naming Convention for indexes

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, naming-conventions, entity-framework-6.1

I understand how to add conventions to the code first (with migrations) project. I have successfully managed to perform the table names and even changed GUID Id fields to non-clustered.

But I have not found how to change the default index name that EF supplies when no name is given.

```
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
public string Code { get; set; }

[Index]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

I have these two requirements.  The top index should be named `UX_[schema]_[table]_Code`, the second `IX_[schema]_[table]_Description`

I also have the need to support multiple column indexes where IsUnique will still be UX but the column section is a Camel Case combination of all columns (e.g.  `UX_[schema]_[table]_CodeDescription` if the two columns above where in the same index.

I'm assuming I would need to add this after the IndexAttributeConvention so that all the current functionality will work and create the IndexAnnotations. But I can't find where the Indexes are receiving their initial name if left blank in the Attribute (or Fluent construct).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this annotation: [Index("IndexName")]
or for your example:

```
[Index("IndexName", IsUnique = true)]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes, that is how we are currently getting around the issue.  But it allows our developers to create any name they want and not follow the standards we have in place.
My question was how I can add a convention to name the indexes.